# Isometry of the Sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I am trying to prove that the map $$f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{A\mathbf{x}}{|A\mathbf{x}|}$$ is a diffeomorphism from the sphere $S^2$ to itself which preserves geodesics of the usual Riemannian metric on $S^2$. I can prove this map is a diffeomorphism but for the preserving of geodesics is it enough to say that since geodesics on the sphere are great circles which all have the same length, this map must preserve the length of the geodesics? Thanks.

Comment: What's *A* then, any matrix?

Comment: At first it just says A is invertible but then it changes to a diagonal matrix with nonzero entries on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

not an isometry. Does NOT preserve lengths. On the other hand; a great circle is the intersection of the sphere with a 2-plane through the origin. As long as $A$ is nonsingular, it maps any 2-plane through the origin to some other 2-plane through the origin, then division by the norm maps this (setwise) to a great circle.

For an example you can calculate and draw, take the 1-sphere in the ordinary plane and take
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You ought to calculate what happens to the three points
$$ (1,0) , \; \; ( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} , \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} ), \; \; ( 0,1) $$

Comment: My mistake, the question said 'show that f preserves geodesics of the metric'. Thanks.